# Wait for several backbone models to save using $.when.apply

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-model

I'm trying to save several backbone models (not in a collection) and execute code after they all get saved.

This is my code simplified:

```
var requestsArray = modelsArray.map(function(model) {
    return model.save();
});

$.when.apply(undefined, requestsArray)
    .done(function() {
        console.log('DONE CALLBACK');
        console.log('ARGS', arguments);
     })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log('FAILED');
        console.log('ARGS', arguments);
    });
```

But when I run this - the `done` callback gets fired immediately and it doesn't wait for the ajax requests to finish.

Why is that?

Comment: Does `$.when.apply($, requestsArray)` make any difference?

Comment: Nope, same result

Comment: Will it be possible to reproduce this in an [mcve]?

Comment: I played with some sample demo and managed to develop this: https://jsfiddle.net/1s0kzy4o/44/ - as you'll see - the `Global fail` console log doesn't wait for all the requests to fail. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't happen directly with requests :(

I had to do it this way:

```
var deferredsArray = modelsArray.map(function(model) {
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();
    model.save().then(function() {
          dfd.resolve();
        }, function() {
          dfd.reject();
        });
    return dfd;
});

$.when.apply(undefined, deferredsArray)
    .done(function() {
        console.log('ALL SUCCESSFUL');
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log('AT LEAST ONE FAILED');
    });
```

And when when all are successful - then the `done` method of `$.when` gets called.